# How to avoid auto starting playback when importing playlist in iTunes library

Tags: itunes, windows

Whenever i import a large folder into iTunes i have the problem that if in one of the subfolders there is a playlist, it will auto start playing. How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

I just delete the m3u and pls files:

```
find ~/Music -iname '*.m3u' -o -iname '*.pls' -delete
```